# How to make "dispatch" as export function in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

This is my dispatch function:

**DispatchRecipeID.js**

```
    import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    import { UpdateRecipeID } from "../store/action/recipeId";
    
    const DispatchRecipeID = (id) => { 

      const dispatch = useDispatch(); // dispatch
    
      dispatch(UpdateRecipeID(id));
    
    };
    
    export default DispatchRecipeID;
```

---

Now I am use this **DispatchRecipeID()** function in another **React JS** file.

**Navbar.js**

```
        import React, { useState } from "react";
        import DispatchRecipeID from "../../middleware/DispatchRecipeID";

    
    const Navbar = () => {

            // inputbox value
            const [input, setInput] = useState("");
            // get search item info from inputID. using inputID.id
            const [inputID, setInputID] = useState(null);

            // search function
            const dispatchRecipeID = ()=>{
              if(input !== "" && input !== null ){
               DispatchRecipeID(inputID.id)
              }
              return
            }
          
            // ....... some code
            return(
                <div>
                  <input type="text" value={input}   onChange={(event,value)=>{ setInputID(value) }} /> 
                  <button onClick={dispatchRecipeID(input)} >Search</button> 
                </div>
            )
            
  }

  export default Navbar;
```

---

But I get error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component.

Full Error Here:

> react-dom.development.js:14906 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call.
> Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
> This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.
>    at Object.throwInvalidHookError (react-dom.development.js:14906:1)
>    at useContext (react.development.js:1504:1)
>    at useReduxContext (useReduxContext.js:21:1)
>    at useStore (useStore.js:20:1)
>    at useDispatch (useDispatch.js:17:1)
>    at DispatchRecipeID (DispatchRecipeID.js:6:1)
>    at searchFunc (Navbar.js:71:1)
>    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
>    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
>    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)

[image]

---

How to fix this error? And I want use **DispatchRecipeID() function** at "3 or 4 JS" files like as **Navbar.js**

please help me, and thanks :)

Comment: Do what the message says :D `Call Hooks from React function components.`. `Call Hooks from custom Hooks` . https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: @Jackson Kasi I have the same problem. What did you do?

Comment: hi @happy-coconut. have a nice day! I change this method, you just see my code:  [github](https://github.com/jacksonkasi0/cooking-time/blob/master/src/components/Navbar/Navbar.js)   ----------   and read my blog about it: [dev blog](https://dev.to/jacksonkasi/cook-react-with-spoonacular-api-how-to-hack-api-5cj7) ----- but if you want to make "dispatch" as export function in React JS, you can use [redux thunk](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/redux-thunk-explained-with-examples/) ------ if you have any doubt please contact me on Mail: **nammalvar888@gmail.com**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for reminding  the one of the important rules in the react hooks that you can't use hooks inside the nested functions and they will not work if you brake this rule

check your all component

Answer (score 1):

DispatchRecipeID.js

```
import { store } from 'redux/store';
```

instead of

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
```

and call dispatch as a key in store

```
const DispatchRecipeID = (id) => { 
    store.dispatch(UpdateRecipeID(id));
};
```